# How to disconnect the network between nodes inside a Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop

I want to inject some faults into a hadoop distributed system. I have built a cluster with 3 nodes using the docker containers. What if I want to disconnect one node? Can I just stop the ssh service on a working node?

Plus, what if I want to simulate the disk full fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that will make the machine not reachable will do, yet spark and hadoop use the RPC protocol to communicate and not ssh, so stopping ssh won't be enough for your case

Spark use a random port on the worker nodes so you can't just block one and expect the node to not be reachable.

On the other hand Hadoop have default port:

https://kontext.tech/column/hadoop/265/default-ports-used-by-hadoop-services-hdfs-mapreduce-yarn

For your use case in general just kill the docker container to simulate a node failure.

Comment: Thanks! It really works. I just stop the docker container. BTW, do you have any idea to make the disk or CPU of one node full? I want to simulate the 'disk/cpu full' fault to test the stability of my program.

Comment: Either you create enough content to make the disk full or either you reduce the size of the partition you alloacated to for hdfs node, I would go with the second.

For the cpu I would maximize the number of core you can use per executor and code fork bomb inside a map.

You can do that with the spark-submit parameter executor-cores